# How to shuffle array of objects to a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a huge array of objects. These objects are like this:

```
data = [
    {
        content: {
            ...,
            depth: 1
        },
        subContent: []
    },
    {
        content: {
            ...,
            depth: 2
        },
        subContent: []
    },
    {
        content: {
            ...,
            depth: 3
        },
        subContent: []
    },{
        content: {
            ...,
            depth: 2
        },
        subContent: []
    },
    {
        content: {
            ...,
            depth: 1
        },
        subContent: []
    },
]
```

I need it like this:

```
result = [
    {
        content: {
            ...,
            depth: 1
        },
        subContent: [
            {
                content: {
                    ...,
                    depth: 2
                },
                subContent: [
                    {
                        content: {
                            ...,
                            depth: 3
                        },
                        subContent: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                content: {
                    ...,
                    depth: 2
                },
                subContent: []
            },
        ], 
        {
            content: {
                ...,
                depth: 1
            },
            subContent: []
        },
    },
]
```

I need the result array with the larger depth number inside the previous smaller subContent. I used a for loop starting at the end of the array and going i--, where I push the higher depth inside the next subContent if its depth+1 is equal to the depth and remove the index from array after.

```
for (let i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i].content.depth === arr[i-1].content.depth + 1) {
    arr[i-1].subContent.push(arr[i]);
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    let index = this.findNextLowerIndex(arr[i].content.depth, arr);
    
    // console.log(index);
    if (arr[index]) {
      arr[index].subContent.push(arr[i]);
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}




findNextLowerIndex(depth: number, arr: any[]): number {
    let findIndex = depth - 1;

    for (let i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i].content.depth === findIndex) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This kind of works execpt for when there are several subContent when the layers of the array are like 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1. What I get is 4->3 nested, 4->3->2->1 nested but not 4->3 nested inside the 2 of the 4->3->2->1 nested. Something is missing when there are several layers with subContents.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be the solution that you are looking for.

```js
const data = [
  { content: { depth: 1 }, subContent: [] },
  { content: { depth: 2 }, subContent: [] },
  { content: { depth: 3 }, subContent: [] }, 
  { content: { depth: 2 }, subContent: [] },
  { content: { depth: 1 }, subContent: [] },
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.content.depth === 1) {
    acc.push(curr);
  } else {
    let node = acc[acc.length - 1]; // Selecting last node
    while (node.content.depth !== curr.content.depth - 1) {
      if (node.subContent) {
        node = node.subContent[node.subContent.length - 1];
      } 
    }
    node.subContent.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to adjust a little because my real data starts with depth 0. I cant believe you solved that so quick

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking something like this ?

```js
let data = [{ content: { depth: 1 }, subContent: [] }, { content: { depth: 2 }, subContent: [] }, { content: { depth: 3 }, subContent: [] }, { content: { depth: 2 }, subContent: [] }, { content: { depth: 1 }, subContent: [] },]
let result = [];
for (let item of data) {
    let node = data.find(v => v.content.depth == item.content.depth - 1)?.subContent || result
    node.push(item)
}
console.log(result)
```